# Return last value that isn't an error in each row

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Trying to get some help with an issue I'm having.

In Google Sheets I have a data in columns A to D.

- Column A contains my original list of names.
- Columns B to D contain either a new name or an `#N/A` error.

I'd like a formula in column F that returns the last value in each row of columns A to D that is not an `#N/A` error

Sample Data with desired result in column F:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Raw Data** | **1st Check** | **2nd Check** | **3rd Check** |  | **Final Result** |
| **2** | Kate | Karen | Joe | `Harry` |  | Harry |
| **3** | Audrey | Audrey | `Audrey` | #N/A |  | Audrey |
| **4** | Kam | `Kam` | #N/A | #N/A |  | Kam |
| **5** | Czar | #N/A | `Rio` | #N/A |  | Rio |
| **6** | `Wing` | #N/A | #N/A | #N/A |  | Wing |

Comment: If [Joel's  solution](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/170185/) solved your problem you might consider accepting it.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your explanation of the logic involved is complete, and the examples pictured are truly representative of the real spreadsheet, all of the rules can be replaced with the rule:

In column F, display the rightmost value from columns A to D which is not #N/A.

If that's sufficient, an example formula for cell F2 might resemble:

```
=INDEX(FILTER(A2:D2, LEN(IFNA(A2:D2))), COUNTA(INDEX(FILTER(A2:D2, LEN(IFNA(A2:D2))))))
```

Then select F2, and drag the [fill handle](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/75509) (the little circle at the lower-right of its highlighted outline) down to fill the other rows of F with formulas Sheets will automatically alter to match each row.

That formula just filters out any [blanks](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094081?hl=en) or [#N/A](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093293) cells for the row, counts the remaining names with [COUNTA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093991), then uses that count to return the one at that "distance" into the name list… the name at that [INDEX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242).

Comment: IFNA is not necessary in the formula, LEN achieves what you want: `LEN(A2:D2)` vs. `LEN(IFNA(A2:D2))`

Answer (score 0):

### Another Approach

[Joel's solution](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/170185/) works. This is simply an alternative.

### Basic Formula

```
=INDEX(r,,XMATCH("*",IFNA(r),2,-1))
```

- In the Basic Formula, replace `r` with a reference to a single row of data, such as `A2:D2`.
  <sup>[image]</sup>

### Multi-Row Formula

```
=BYROW(mr, LAMBDA(r,
   INDEX(r,,XMATCH("*",IFNA(r),2,-1))
```

- Replace `mr` with a reference to multiple rows of data. e.g. `A2:D6`
- **Do not** replace `r` in the Multi-Row Formula.  The LAMBDA function will use it as a variable to hold the current row passed in by the BYROW function.
  <sup>[image]</sup>